# UIBlurEffect without extra light "style"

Tags: ios, uiview, blur

In Apples Developer Class-Reference it says that there are three types of blur effects you can apply to a `UIVisualEffectsView`:

```
typedef enum {
   UIBlurEffectStyleExtraLight,
   UIBlurEffectStyleLight,
   UIBlurEffectStyleDark 
} UIBlurEffectStyle;
```

It says:

> - **UIBlurEffectStyleLight**
>
> Creates a blurring effect in the view. The area of the view is the
>   same approximate hue of the underlying view.
>
> Available in iOS 8.0 and later.

I tried to use `UIBlurEffectStyleLight` but clearly this effect adds a white overlay to the view wich i do not want...

[What i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqkRF.png)

[What i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GILhn.png)

Is this even possible with `UIVisualEffectsView` ? Or do i have to use a completely different method of adding a blur ?

Answer (score 0):

`UIVisualEffectsView` is really not that flexible.
I think what you're looking for is something like [FXBlurView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView).